# How does this code for incremental retry back off work?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

```
var source = get('url').retryWhen(
   attempts =>
    attempts
      .zip(Observable.range(1, 3), (_, i) => i)
      .flatMap(i => {
        console.log('delay retry by ' + i + ' second(s)');
        return Rx.Observable.timer(i * 1000);
      });
);
```

Source: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/range.html

So: retryWhen takes a function which takes the errors, and returns an observable representing when to try again.

zip takes n observables and interleaves them, and flatmap is a Monadic bind, transforming an observable into a new observable. My question is, why does zip take an arrow function rather than an observable as its second argument in this instance? And where is the underscore syntax coming from? I presume it means "ignore value of first argument", but where is it coming from? It's passed as an argument to `zip`, so I can only assume it is an observable somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does zip take an arrow function rather than an observable as its second argument in this instance?

It's called projection function, where you can transform the values you receive from zip.

> where is it (underscore) coming from?

`_` is the value emitted by the `attempts` observable, ignored in this case (`_` is a convention for ignored param).

You're basically doing this:

```
attemptsObservable.zip(rangeObservable, (attemptValue, rangeValue) => rangeValue)
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying! could you point me at the docs for this by any chance?

Comment: Unfortunately they're changing the [documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/zip), so you can't find much right now. We have to wait a lil bit.